# prepare clickstream for k-means clustering

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means

i'm new to machine learning algorithms and i'm trying to do a user segmentation based on the users clickstreams of a news website. i have prepared the clickstreams so that i know which user id read which news-category and how many times.

so my table looks something like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| UserID | Category 1 | Category 2 | ... | Category 20
-------------------------------------------------------
| 123    | 4          | 0          | ... | 2
-------------------------------------------------------
| 124    | 0          | 10         | ... | 12
-------------------------------------------------------
```

i'm wondering if the k-means works well for so many categories? would it be better to use percentages instead of whole numbers for the read articles?
 so e.g. user123 read 6 articles overall - 4 of 6 were category 1 so its 66,6% interest in category 1.

another idea would be to pick the 3 most-read categories of each user and transform the table to something like this whereby Interest 1 : 12 means that the user is most interested in Category 12

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| UserID | Interest 1 | Interest 2 | Interest 3
-------------------------------------------------------
| 123    | 1          | 12          | 7
-------------------------------------------------------
| 124    | 12          | 13         | 20
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: So to be clear, you want to make a vector in 20 dimensions and then cluster those? 20 dimensions is not very large at all and very feasible on a laptop (assuming the number of users is not enormous).

Answer (score 0):

K-means will not work well for two main reasons:

1. It is for continuous, dense data. Your data is discrete.
2. It is not robust to outliers, you probably have a lot of noisy data

Answer (score 0):

well, the number of users is not defined because it's a theoretical approach, but because it's a news website let's assume there are millions of users...

would there be another, better algorithm for clustering user groups based on their category interests? and when i prepare the data of the first table so that i have the interest of one user for each category in percentage - the data would be continuous and not discrete - or am i wrong?

Comment: Perhaps chapter 4 of Stephen Boyd's [book](http://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/vmls/)  would be useful. Section 4.4.2 is along the lines of what you're asking (as is 4.5)

Comment: Did that book cluster 500 samples with almost 4500 features? Is this approach prudent given the curse of dimensionality?